# How to get map marker data using Selenium in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the marker positions and it's respective price from the google map in the following url:
https://www.airbnb.com.au/s/2-Rouse-Street--Port-Melbourne--Victoria?page=1&source=filters&airbnb_plus_only=false&checkin=17-11-2016&checkout=18-11-2016&guests=1&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&ss_id=qycq5gv1&allow_override%5B%5D=&s_tag=MM-x-kQG

I've been able to marker location by simply getting the lat/long of the map, and location of the markers by using a grid system. Once you 'superimpose' you get the marker location. However, the issue is I don't know which marker corresponds to which price so I'm wondering how this would get done.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: The markers on the map contain pricing... what exactly are you looking for???